# azure runbook PowerShell script content is not importing in terraform properly in azure automation account

Tags: automation, terraform

I have created azure automation account using terraform. I have save my existing runbook PowerShell script files in local. I have successfully uploaded all the script files at one time while creation of automation account with below code:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example" {
  for_each                = fileset("Azure_Runbooks/", "*")
  name                    = split(".", each.key)[0]
  location                = var.location
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  log_verbose             = var.log_verbose
  log_progress            = var.log_progress
  runbook_type            = var.runbooktype
  content                 = each.value
}
```

After running the terraform apply command, all the script files are uploading successfully to the automation account but the content of the PowerShell script is not getting uploaded. I have checked the runbooks in the automation account but there is not content inside the file. I am seeing only the name of the file.

Can some one please help me with above issue.

Answer (score 2):

You assuming `fileset(path, pattern)` returns the contents of the file as `each.value`, but that is not the case. The `each.value` is just the file name.

You need something like:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example" {
  for_each                = fileset("Azure_Runbooks/", "*")
  name                    = split(".", each.key)[0]
  location                = var.location
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  log_verbose             = var.log_verbose
  log_progress            = var.log_progress
  runbook_type            = var.runbooktype
  content                 = file(format("%s%s", "Azure_Runbooks/", each.value)
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Harsha, Thanks for your response. I have tried with above code but still getting below error:
Error: Invalid expression
│
│   on AutomationAccount\main.tf line 58, in resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example":
│   58:   content                 = file(format(%s%s, "Azure_Runbooks/", each.value)
│
│ Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

Comment: I forgot to put the` %%s` into parenthesis. Try it again.

Comment: still seeing the same error. Can you please provide me the code for 'content' again please.

Comment: Still seeing the error below:

Comment: Error: Too many function arguments
│
│   on AutomationAccount\main.tf line 58, in resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example":
│   58:   content                 = file(format("%s%s"), "Azure_Runbooks/", each.value)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value will be known only after apply
│
│ Function "file" expects only 1 argument(s).

Comment: Hi Team, Still facing the above error. Kindly help us to fix my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue with correct code:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example" {
  for_each                = fileset("Azure_Runbooks/", "*")
  name                    = split(".", each.key)[0]
  location                = var.location
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  log_verbose             = var.log_verbose
  log_progress            = var.log_progress
  runbook_type            = var.runbooktype
  content                 = file(format("%s%s" , "Azure_Runbooks/" , each.key))
}
```

Thanks @YoungGova for your help.